# How to check what keys of an NSDictionary are available?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

What I'm trying to do is check how deep in the Dictionary I am. My JSON has two possibilities:

```
stop-schedule:
   0:
      route:
   1:
      route:
```

or

```
stop-schedule:
   route:
```

so I'm checking if I need to go deeper or not.

Normally I would simply do something like

```
[dict objectForKey:@"0"]
```

to check if the key exists (will return nill if not) however for some reason I'm getting an error when testing it on iOS.

```
[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: That is not a dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now read the error message attentively.

---

Your `dict` is not really a dictionary but an array. It doesn't have keys. If you want to make sure it's of a certain class, use reflection:

```
if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // object
} else if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    // array
} else {
    // fragment or `nil`
}
```

Comment: How silly of me, of course. Maybe I should get some rest and continue in the morning... Thank you.

Comment: @DeKay Yes, sleep a bit, definitely. You're welcome. :)